# application of C++

Tags: c++

everybody, I've just finished my course `Introduction to Systems Programming`, the last part of it was C++, I learned a lot of stuff, but all I used to write was some `console programs`, I want to begin to write something new on c++ (something  with `graphic windows` or maybe `small game`) to improve my knowledge, from which point can I start and which books can You recommend, I found a lot materials but I don't want to waste my time for bad books, so need Your advice, thanks in advance

Comment: Start looking into Qt framework for GUI design in C++.

Comment: can You recommend some book, please?

Comment: as for a book: http://qt.nokia.com/developer/getting-started/getting-started#read-the-official-qt

Answer (score 0):

I once read the book "Tricks of the windows game programming gurus"

[http://www.amazon.com/Tricks-Windows-Game-Programming-Gurus/dp/0672323699](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672323699)

All though it was the only book i ever read about game programming, I think it's a great book. All the samples are in C++.

It has a lot of mathematical and physics equations that have to do with simple game programming and graphics techniques. It also teaches you to work with DirectX.

I read it a while back (at least a couple of years) so it could be that it's outdated by now...

Comment: thanks a lot, I study now openGL, so I think it will be good combination